# Cmpsd not working as I expected

Tags: assembly, x86

I am very confused about this code:

```
.section .data
    value1:
            .ascii "This is a test string"
    value2:
            .ascii "This is a test String"
.section .text
.globl main
main:
    movl $1, %eax
    leal value1, %esi
    leal value2, %edi
    movl $21, %ecx
    cld
    repe cmpsb
    je equal
    movl %ecx, %ebx
    int $0x80
equal:
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

The output is the following:

```
es@elegy:~/ATT$ ./cmpstest2
es@elegy:~/ATT$ echo $?
5
```

How come ECX contains 5? I was expecting 15, counting from the beginning of the string.

Comment: `ecx` is counting down from `21`.

Comment: Yeah, CPU usually works according to specification, not programmers expectation. Debugger may help as well (either use the GNU standard gdb, or for such small task you may try [edb](https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger/wiki)). To get the char offset, try `subl value1,%esi` `movl %esi,%ebx`  (I'm not sure about the gas syntax, but you get the idea?). And I would move the `eax=1` right ahead of each `int 0x80` just to make the source easier to read (locality).

Comment: Thank you very much I understood now that ecx counts down no matter what.

Comment: It *has* to count down, that's how [the `REPE` prefix](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_279.html) works. You initialized it to 21. It's hard to imagine how you expected anything else.